# How to both update and select in a same operation

Tags: t-sql

How do I do this in TSQL? : [How UPDATE and SELECT at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934369/how-update-and-select-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TSQL equivalent of the answer in the linked question would be something like

```
UPDATE [table]
SET foo=1
OUTPUT INSERTED.*, DELETED.*
WHERE boo=2
```

In an update statement you can use `INSERTED` to get the "after" values and `DELETED` the "before" values.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).