# How to set all rows in column 0 when all rows reach 1

Tags: python, sqlite, triggers, sql-update

i have a function that needs to update all rows to 0 after all rows have 1..

I have made some save systhem it needs to work like this. I got multiple employee, after i use a button 2 mails will be send. After the mail send savecounter will update to 1 and if i close the program then he knows where tho start again.

my question now is, how do i make a query that checks if all savecounter rows is 1. and if so update it all to 0.  what do i need to do thanxx

```
def savecountercheck():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('schoonschip.db')
    cursorr =  conn.cursor()

    employe = cursorr.execute('SELECT savecounter FROM employee ')
    selection =  cursorr.fetchall()
    for i in selection:
        if i ==  1:  
            cursorr.execute('UPDATE employee SET savecounter = 0 ' )
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print(selection)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How UPDATE and SELECT at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934369/how-update-and-select-at-the-same-time)

Comment: That answer is about Postgres but SQlite supports the same syntax, as far as I can tell: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that 0 and 1 are the only possible values for the column `savecounter`.

If you want to automate the task, so that every time the column `savecounter` is updated from 0 to 1 and there is no other 0 in the column then the whole table gets updated with 0s in `savecounter`, you could create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER emp_reset_savecounter AFTER UPDATE OF savecounter ON employee
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE WHEN NEW.savecounter = 0 THEN RAISE(IGNORE) END;
  SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT MIN(savecounter) FROM employee) = 0 THEN RAISE(IGNORE) END;
  UPDATE employee SET savecounter = 0;
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=5ca8b9b33df56ae38e91aa162c580b23).

If you want to do it in your app, you will have to execute this `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE employee 
SET savecounter = 0
WHERE (SELECT MIN(savecounter) FROM employee) = 1;
```

See the [[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=a988e98ab4fa53ab644f4225f428c020)][2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=a988e98ab4fa53ab644f4225f428c020).